# What are the benefits of not using doctype

Tags: html, doctype

I am very **familiar with the doctypes purposes and differences**,
I keep seeing websites without doctype, I mean really **big website** (xerox, godaddy etc.) that on some internal (not homepage) pages just don't set a doctype.

**Are there solid reasons for that? Probably a mistake?**
(I am asking these questions to know how crucial it is to support it)

P.S
I'm working on a third-party javascript/html/css application, so my goal is to create the widest support possible for our product.

Comment: You should add a doctype to your page to help the browser know how to render it.  With old versions of IE, an incorrect doctype could put it into compatibility mode or even quirks mode!  A simple `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your page should tell browsers to use the correct render mode.

Comment: It looks like that if your page is XHTML5, then a DOCTYPE is optional.

Comment: I also would like to know is there are side effects like, wrong compact mode, how old browser will act, etc..
And both of your comments are not really answering the question.

Comment: If old pages have been thoroughly tested on many browsers without a doctype and are known to work correctly, adding a doctype subsequently risks changing the behaviour in undesirable ways, so there is benefit in just leaving well alone. *New* pages should include a doctype to lessen their required testing effort.